# tortoise svn is not responding in windows 7 sp1 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, tortoise-svn

I have a Windows 7 SP1 64-bit. My company requires me to use SVN, so I installed TortoiseSVN 1.7.2 64-bit.

however, if I try to connect to my company's server, the checkout window and repo browser window don't respond.

I came from 1.7.1. i thought this 1.7.2 update might solve the problem but it did not.

A few quirks I observed:

- Browsing the repo via Firefox works normally.
- When observing other repos such as `svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk` it works normally.
- I tried it (connecting to my company's server) on Windows XP (32-bit) on VirtualBox and it works normally.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.